# Event onClick with React - function not called

Tags: reactjs, function

I have a Js file with some functions inside.

```
const addProductToCart = document.querySelectorAll('.add-product-to-cart');

ProductToCart.forEach(el => {
        el.addEventListener('click', e => {
            const redirect = e.target.dataset.redirect;
            if (!redirect) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            let product = e.target.dataset.product
            if (product) {
                fetch(baseUrl + "cookie/product/" + product,
                    {method: 'POST'}
                ).then(r => console.log(r))
            }
            animateIcon.animate(translations["Your sample has been successfully added to your cart"], 'cart');
        });
    });
```

With inspection of the HTML code I can see event on each product:
[image: HTML inspection code]

My function to add a sample works, but not in my render React (I just added the name of the class).

```
<a href={""} className={"add-product-to-cart"} data-product={product.id}>Test</a>
```

But in this case, I can't see the event and my function is not called:
[image]

So:
Why my Js doesn't work on this page, is there something to add/do about "event" works?
What can I do to import all logic from another Js file.

Thanks in advance, I am new to React...

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest of your react component its difficult to tell but if the function isnt being called did you bind it?

```
class YOURNAME extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.addProductToCart = this.addProductToCart.bind(this);
}
```

Then outline the function

```
addProductToCart(){
//what you want to do here
```

}

Your current button is fine.

Comment: Hi Math, I can to add a sample with this code:

`addProductToCart = e => {
        const baseUrl = document.getElementById('baseUrl').getAttribute('value');
        const redirect = e.target.dataset.redirect;
        if (!redirect) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        let product = e.target.dataset.product
        if (product) {
            fetch(baseUrl + "/cookie/product/" + product, {method: 'POST'}))
    }
}`

But this function is just a copy/past from my Js file "downloadsAndCart.js" and all rest of other function doesn't work (animation of basket, alert...).

Comment: Why do you have `class AnimateIcon`? Thats not going to call that function

Comment: No I know, but I need that function to show that a sample has been added.

- I have a Js file - downloadsAndCart.js. Inside I have all logic about order samples (cookie, alert, basket's animation...). I can order a sample on product details (page of a single product). When I inspect the code of the button, I can see the event attached to classe name (add-product-to-cart). Function from downloadsAndCart.js.

- I have a page with all products and I would like to add a cart icon to add in the basket each product. How to get the same logic for this page. How can I import downloadsAndCart.js

Comment: It is best to just rewrite it in reactJS. You will need to add things like "ref's" for the components you are trying to trigger.

Comment: Really, isn't there a solution and just import this Js file into reactJs file? Or add this event to my render... 

Because currently I have 483 lines in "downloadsAndCart.js" and reconstruct the totality in react...